# Creating a index for unique combination of columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I got a set of data just like that:

```
df = data.frame(A = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9),
                B = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5),
                D = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.3))
```

but i need to create a index for all unique combination of A, B and D. Just like that:

```
   index   A   B   D
1      1 0.1 0.5 0.2
2      2 0.3 0.4 0.1
3      3 0.7 0.8 0.5
4      4 0.9 0.6 0.8
5      5 0.5 0.8 0.6
6      6 0.4 0.5 0.7
7      2 0.3 0.4 0.1
8      7 0.3 0.5 0.3
9      4 0.9 0.6 0.8
10     8 0.9 0.5 0.3
```

Note that the combination between A, B and D is the same for rows 4 and 9 and for rows 2 and 7. Therefore, they receive the same index value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code. Maybe the naming of indices have a slight difference than your output but the logic is the same:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(A, B, D) %>%
  mutate(index = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(index)

# A tibble: 10 x 4
       A     B     D index
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1   0.1   0.5   0.2     1
 2   0.3   0.4   0.1     2
 3   0.3   0.4   0.1     2
 4   0.3   0.5   0.3     3
 5   0.4   0.5   0.7     4
 6   0.5   0.8   0.6     5
 7   0.7   0.8   0.5     6
 8   0.9   0.5   0.3     7
 9   0.9   0.6   0.8     8
10   0.9   0.6   0.8     8
```

Comment: Great function cur_group_id(). Did not know aboutthis function. I will give it a try now

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(index = match(str_c(A, B, D), unique(str_c(A, B, D)))) %>% 
   arrange(index)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` option

```
df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(index = 1:n()) %>%
  left_join(x = df)
```

gives

```
     A   B   D index
1  0.1 0.5 0.2     1
2  0.3 0.4 0.1     2
3  0.7 0.8 0.5     3
4  0.9 0.6 0.8     4
5  0.5 0.8 0.6     5
6  0.4 0.5 0.7     6
7  0.3 0.4 0.1     2
8  0.3 0.5 0.3     7
9  0.9 0.6 0.8     4
10 0.9 0.5 0.3     8
```